# Game different walking pictures?

Tags: vb.net

Below is the code for when player moves, I want to make the picture of player moving up go when he moves, but right now it just blinks the up picture then goes back to down...

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

```
    Private Sub walkup_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles walkup.Tick
    If moveup.Visible = False Then
        'moveup.Show()
        moveup.Visible = True
        movedown.Hide()
        Me.moveup.Location = New Point(Me.movedown.Location.X, Me.movedown.Location.Y)
    End If

    If Me.moveup.Location.Y > 12 Then
        Me.moveup.Location = New Point(Me.moveup.Location.X, Me.moveup.Location.Y - 1)
    End If
    Static moveCount As Integer = 1
    moveCount += 1
    If moveCount = 10 Then
        moveCount = 1
        moveup.Hide()
        movedown.Show()
        walkup.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't see anything blatantly wrong with the posted code.  Are you sure the Timer is being turned on?  What is the Interval setting for it?

Comment: To check what the button pressed was as a event? I don't thing int main() is a keapress event...

Comment: I'm sorry...is there a question there?  Your response doesn't make much sense in the context of the question, or what I asked about.

Comment: Its always going to show the up picture because you're setting it to true whenever its false, and if its not false, its already showing...

Comment: only if movecount is 10, but some reason when this line of code  `code`If moveup.Visible = False Then`code` is their... It skips straight to having 10 movecount and without it it waits...